# How to show Comments (created with entity form) only to the Admin user and logged in?

Tags: views, comments, entities

I'm cool fresh drupal :)

I'm trying to filter views in a content type entityform for the user logged in and admin. In practice this form through the admin and user login should communicate.

problem: On page dein results I see only the one who wrote the admin, but the user responses.

Then I node (private area) with filtered content to the user, so each user sees the content added by the administrator for each user.

I would like each user to comment on the content that the administrator has reserved for each user.

Now I tried with modules or with the comments of core drupal views of seeps into single user comments and the admin.

example: 
There are three users, User "A" User "B", User "C", 
Each of these users comments posted content dall'aministratore reserved for them. The administrator shall have commmenti User "A".

The same node (private area) would like to display the comments and views with only the user "A" and the responses made ​​administrator user "A". And so also for users B, C, D, F etc. ...

I hope to be as clear as possible. :)

Where am I wrong? 
help me. :)

Sorry for my bad english [image][image]

Comment: Can you make your question bit more clearer?

Comment: I edited the question. @Aparna

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might try updating PERMISSIONS.  By default, EntityForms only allows administrator to view, edit, or delete.  If you want a user to be able to view their own EntityForm submissions, you have to update the permission for this.  You can find it under PEOPLE->PERMISSIONS->EntityForms->View own entityform submissions-> [check] AUTHENTICATED USER.

Good Luck!

Chrisjan